# How to avoid conflicting onclick functions on a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component below: there are 2 usecases, when I click on the entire `div` some function is executed and when I click on just the `<img>`, some function is executed.
I have 2 props defined, `onClick`, when clicked on the entire `div`
and `onIconClick` when clicked on the img.

```
export default class List extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    this.props.onClick();
  }
  onIconClick() {
    this.props.onIconClick();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style="width:200px, height: 200px" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
        <img src="delete.png" onClick={this.onIconClick.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

here is the way I call the component:

```
export default class MyApp extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    //some execution
  }
  onIconClick() {
    //some other execution
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <List
        onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
        onIconClick={this.onIconClick.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Now my issue is the `this.onClick.bind(this)` gets called all the time even when I click the image, hence I never get to `this.onIconClick.bind(this)`.

I tried reversing the order:

```
 <List onIconClick={this.onIconClick.bind(this)} onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} />
```

still doesn't work, not sure what selection criteria I should use in order to distinguish between these 2 clicks.

Any ideas??

Comment: why those event handlers are defined outside of classes?

Comment: my bad, fixed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.onIconClick = this.onIconClick.bind(this);
  }
  onClick() {
    alert("Parent-onClick()");
  }
  onIconClick() {
    alert("Parent-onIconClick()");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child onClick={this.onClick} onIconClick={this.onIconClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.onIconClick = this.onIconClick.bind(this);
  }
  onClick() {
    this.props.onClick();
  }
  onIconClick(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.props.onIconClick();
  }
  render() {
    let styles = {
      height: "500px",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      paddingTop: "20px"
    };
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick} className="img-wrapper" style={styles}>
        <img
          onClick={this.onIconClick}
          src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"
          alt="img"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

The idea is using `stopPropagation()` method of the [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) instance.

---

> Your event handlers will be passed instances of SyntheticEvent, a
>   c*ross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event*. It has the
>   same interface as the browser’s native event, including
>   *stopPropagation()* and *preventDefault()*, **except the events work
>   identically across all browsers.**
>
> If you find that you need the underlying browser event for some
>   reason, *simply use the **nativeEvent** attribute to get it.*

---

Using the [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) 's methods allows our code to behave exactly the same across all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `e.stopPropagation()`. If you want to use `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()`, you can use in the same line.

```js
onIconClick(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    this.props.onIconClick();
  }
```

Comment: where do I add this?